# Zero-downtime repartitioning on postgres 12

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

I have a ~1 billion row table called `things`. The things transition through several states (tracked in the `state` column), eventually ending up in either a `broken` or `finished` state.

`broken` or `finished` rows almost never change, but we need to read them from time to time. The data is very cold. Rows in other states change a lot, so they lead to a lot of bloat and autovacuums.

We're using postgres 12, so this seems like a good case for declarative partitioning. It feels like a small-hot table for active things makes sense, then move the rows  to larger cold partitions once they stop changing.

Here's a simplified structure we've considered:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE things_id_seq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NO MINVALUE NO MAXVALUE CACHE 1;
CREATE TABLE things (
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('things_id_seq'),
    account_id integer NOT NULL,
    state text NOT NULL,
    value integer NOT NULL
)
PARTITION BY LIST (state);

CREATE TABLE things_default PARTITION OF things DEFAULT;

CREATE TABLE things_finished PARTITION OF things FOR VALUES IN ('finished') PARTITION BY LIST (account_id);
CREATE TABLE things_finished_default PARTITION OF things_finished DEFAULT;
CREATE TABLE things_finished_account_id_1 PARTITION OF things_finished FOR VALUES IN (1);
CREATE TABLE things_finished_account_id_2 PARTITION OF things_finished FOR VALUES IN (2);

CREATE TABLE things_broken PARTITION OF things FOR VALUES IN ('broken');

CREATE INDEX things_id ON things USING btree (id);
CREATE INDEX things_state ON things USING btree (state);
CREATE INDEX things_account ON things USING btree (account_id);
CREATE INDEX things_value ON things USING btree (value);
```

Over half of the things are in a `finished` state, so that cold partition is still quite large. To keep it from growing too large, we've included sub-partitions for some large accounts.

Is feasible it is to re-partition if we need to adjust the structure down the track, or do we need to get the partitioning scheme right at the start? Currently we manage to apply nearly all schema changes with no user-visible downtime - is it possible to re-partition without long-held locks that impact user traffic?

For example, what if I want to add a new sub-partition to the things_finished table because an account has grown quite large? This seems to work:

```
BEGIN;

CREATE TABLE things_finished_account_id_3 ( like things including all );

INSERT INTO things_finished_account_id_3 SELECT * FROM things WHERE state = 'finished' and account_id = 3;

DELETE FROM things WHERE state = 'finished' AND account_id = 3;

ALTER TABLE things_finished ATTACH PARTITION things_finished_account_id_3 FOR VALUES IN (3);

COMMIT;
```

However the `ALTER TABLE` takes out a `AccessExclusiveLock` on the `things_finished_default` table, blocking all reads and writes to that partition for the last part of the transaction.

Maybe an alternative partitioning scheme will be easier to re-partition on a live database?